# Can in-situ mean in person?

Tags: idiomatic-language, latin

Can I say "I prefer texting to talking to someone in-situ"?

I feel like I heard someone say that before. But I am not able to find the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic choice would be **face-to-face**, not *in situ*.  Someone might have said *in situ*, but it was probably meant to be funny; at least many people would take it as such.

Answer (score 2):

*In situ* is not a common English phrase in casual conversation.  It's a more formal term that means "in its original or proper place", although [the meaning can vary considerably depending where it's used.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ)

If you want to use it about a person, you may do so *ironically* to imply that person never leaves a particular location, as if you are a biologist going to visit a rare or delicate species which must not be moved from its local environment.

> Since Greg never leaves his mother's basement, and he doesn't answer texts, I went to talk to him *in situ*.